# Does Settings Panel for Android Q work on Wear OS?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to implement automated Wifi enable for my app, which works good for devices before Android Q. However on devices with higher android version, I cannot bring up the Settings Panel. Is it Settings Panel supported at all?

How I enable wifi:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        Intent panelIntent = new
                Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY);
        startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0);
    } else {
        // for previous android version
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
                this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
```

The error I get on Android R Wear OS emulator/device:

> ```
>  Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.panel.action.INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY }
> ```

Comment: Have you tried Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS?